# How to compare two columns in R data frame and return 0 or 1 in the third column based on the comparison?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns(both are dates) and a million rows. I have to compare both the dates and return value in the third column. i.e if date in column A is greater than date in column B, return 1 in column C.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried? This is very easy to achieve in R provided you have your data set up correctly, can you show a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data?

Comment: `DF$C = DF$A > DF$B` ?

Comment: yes, my dates are set correctly using as.date command. I have never done comparison and returned value accordingly before.

Comment: @MichaelChirico will this alone return 1 or zero? I would try it but my rstudio is currently running a task on a large dataframe

Comment: @stef1 you can start a new Rstudio session and try it on example data.

Comment: because you have million rows, I provide `data.table` way for u below to manipulate large data.

Answer (score 1):

In `base`:

```
DF$C <- as.numeric(DF$A > DF$B)
```

In `dplyr`:

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(C = as.numeric(A > B))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(dt)
dt$A <- as.Date(dt$A)
dt$B <- as.Date(dt$B)
```

Here are two ways you can try:

```
dt[, C := ifelse(A > B, 1, 0)]
```

or

```
dt[, C := 0][A > B, C := 1]
```

In second way, you can change to `dt[, C := 1][A <= B, C := 0]` by checking which has less obs.

Maybe you need to provide a little reproducible example.

Comment: These are very roundabout ways of achieving something that you can do very directly in R.

Comment: I know this is roundabout. But if the data just contains million rows, `data.table` combined with this is OK maybe. Is there other ways to do super large data in this question?

Comment: I say this is roundabout because the result of `DF$A > DF$B` is so close to the desired answer that it seems unnecessary to add extra steps on top of it,  or send it through `ifelse`. `as.numeric(A > B)` is simple and clean.